# GenerateRadioButton() issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I created a tag helper that renders a radio list.  It works as expected.  However, I cannot get the tag helper to render with the option selected when `rbSelected=true`.

```
bool rbSelected = true;
object inputAttrib = new { @id = inputId };

if(rbselected)
    inputAttrib = new { @id = inputId, @checked = "checked" }; //have also tried "True" and "true"

_htmlGenerator.GenerateRadioButton(ViewContext, 
        explorer, 
        aspForExpression.Name, 
        item.Value, 
        rbSelected, 
        inputAttrib)
```

As mentioned in the code comments.  I have also tried with:

1. `@checked = "True"`
2. `@checked = "true"`
3. `@checked = true`
4. Omitting `@checked` from the htmlAttributes all-together

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried integer constants? Like 1 or "1"?

Comment: @G0867532 Thanks for the suggestion.  Just tried.  Same result unfortunately

Comment: Hm. Try "isChecked" as attribute and boolean as value.

Comment: @G0867532 still no-go :(

Comment: That is odd. I've found documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.ihtmlgenerator.generateradiobutton?view=aspnetcore-2.1 stating "isChecked"

Comment: @G0867532 my bad.  I thought you meant as part of htmlAttributes.  The 5th method parameter "isChecked" is accepting `rbSelected` which is always `true`.  I thought this would render the radiobutton as checked... but it isn't for some reason

Comment: Thanks @G0867532 for your help!  I just figured it out.  Was using the wrong modelexplorer...  updated that and it resolved everything.  Thanks again

Comment: @Frase nice to hear! I recommend you to answer your own question. That may help someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original question left out part of the context that answered it.  I had incorrectly used `explorer` as the `ModelExplorer` in the `GenerateRadioButton` method.  I should have used the one associated with the list items - `aspForExplorer`

`var aspForExplorer = aspForExpression.ModelExplorer.GetExplorerForExpression(aspForExpression.Metadata, aspForExpression.Model);`